# Visual Studio 2010 + Python 3.3

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I have download Visual Studio 2010 and Im looking for Python tool 3.3, but it said that Visual Studio 2013 is required. Download 2013 is it my only way to get Python?

Many Thanks

Comment: You do not need Visual Studio installed to install Python. You do, however, need it for some of the extra tools like [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) if you're on Windows. If you are referring to [Python Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx) that is an extension for Visual Studio, so obviously you would need Visual Studio installed.

Comment: @CoryKramer you don't need VS, period.  Not even for pip.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @corekramer you need the VS c++ runtime not all of VS.

Comment: Also pip doesn't need it. Many packages, however do (notably pandas/bumpy/scipy)

Comment: @CoryKramer slight correction, you only need the compiler from VS if you are installing C extensions via pip.  Pure python modules don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [PTVS](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation)? It seems to be a solution for you by installing a 2010 VS version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @remus Thanks! I really wanted to help by commenting, but I have 46 reputation now.